# Are heuristic evaluations valuable?

Tags: usability, heuristics, discount

The literature seems to contradict itself. One side says they're great if conducted correctly (multiple experts) but the other side says even with multiple experts many issues are missed.

The gold standard seems to suggest that Heuristic Evaluationss need to be conducted in conjunction with usability testing (which I don't disagree).

Is it still worth it to provide a client *some* feedback on usability issues if time or resources aren't available?

Answer (score 2):

They're valuable, but almost every other technique is *more* valuable.  They can help with *low-hanging fruit* issues, and to help you (or your client, if you're external) to identify places to focus those other techniques.

If you've created from the ground up with sound UX practices then heuristics are more of a QA measure than design work - they help you check you've not made stupid mistakes rather than ensuring you've created the best experience.

But if you're coming in to a project cold and need to get moving fast, a heuristic evaluation (and some work to improve what it reveals) can clear a lot of the clutter away and help you find the real meaty problems they're hiding.

Valuable as a tool, but also sorely limited.